# Excel VBA Calling modules

Tags: vba, excel

So I have put together this code, but I am having trouble running it. I tried calling on the sub routines, but nothing was happening. I am stuck on how to call the modules I have created. I have also created a  MainMenu() sub and I am wondering if that was maybe a mistake and I should have run my MainMenu from sheet1. Maybe someone has a better idea.

My original plan was to create a commandbutton where if clicked module1, which contains the MainMenu() would run.

```
Sub CommandButton1()

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Within module1 there is a loop that runs and calls the other three modules

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim row_sum As Integer

Sub Main()
'Finding the last row
row_sum = 0

'row check upto 5,000
For k = 1 To 5000
    ' if cells in k are blank then the row_check = 0, else row_check = 1
    If CStr(Cells(k, 1)) = "" Then row_check = 0 Else row_check = 1
    'adding the total of row_check to row_sum
    row_sum = row_sum + row_check
Next k
For j = 2 To row_sum
    Call Module2
    Call Module3
    Call Module4

Next j

End Sub
```

I can not figure out where I am going wrong exactly. if anyone sees something I am missing please let me know. I appreciate any help

Comment: You shouldn't call modules, but subs or functions, try using the names of your functions instead of `Module 2` etc...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That's quite a lot of code to go over, mind editing it into a [mcve] that would be helpful for others having a similar issue? Like @cybernetic.nomad said, you don't call modules, you call *procedures* and *functions*. Modules are just containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all the code we needed to see:

> ```
> Call Module2
> Call Module3
> Call Module4
> ```

=)

You don't "call" modules, modules are containers for procedures and functions. What you "call", is procedures and functions. So if you have `Sub DoSomething()` in `Module5`, you can invoke it like this:

```
Module5.DoSomething
```

Or, if there's no `DoSomething` anywhere else:

```
DoSomething
```

Just like you would invoke `VBA.Interaction.MsgBox` like `MsgBox "Hello!"`. Note that you don't need to have a `Call` keyword anywhere for it to work.

---

Your `Module2.SourceApprove` procedure has parameters. So you can't just do `SourceApprove` or `Module2.SourceApprove`, VBA will complain that a *parameter is not optional*.

So you supply the parameters in a comma-separated list of values:

```
Module2.SourceApprove "first", "second", "third", 42
```

These could be variables, too.

```
Dim foo As Long
foo = 42

Module2.SourceApprove "first", "second", "third", foo
```

Consider using meaningful names for your parameters - that way *IntelliSense* will help you know what values to provide. You can (should) also specify a type for the parameters, so that "first" can't be provided as a value for a parameter that requires a number.

```
Sub SourceApprove(ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long, ByVal k As Long, ByVal row_sum As Double)
```

Comment: Wouldn't  `Call Module2`run into a compiler error? The TO's code can't run without a compiler error message.

Comment: @Storax yes, just like `Module2` all by itself. *You don't call a module, you call a function or a procedure*.

Comment: Thank you, this method worked beautifully! I apologies about using too much code. I will keep that in mind next time, thanks again!